# Android studio 3.1.3 not Highlighting deprecated methods

Tags: android, android-studio-3.1.3

I installed android studio 3.1.3 this working properly but this not Highlighting deprecated methods and give below error.(In the other words not  draw a line on
deprecated methods in editor!!!)

```
 uses or overrides a deprecated API.Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

It does not specify which method on which line is deprecated.
Is this a bug in android studio 3.1.3 ?

Comment: Maybe **you're** not using one... An internal library is. `Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details`

Comment: @cricket_007 please more explain me.Thanks.

Comment: Without showing your code in this post, we can't see what you think is deprecated that Android Studio isn't highlight correctly, you can recompile the code, as the warning mentions, and Gradle will show you what actually is deprecated

Comment: @cricket_007 please show my question in this url: [Android studio 3.1.3 not show any error when i use deprecated api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51245031/android-studio-3-1-3-not-show-any-error-when-i-use-deprecated-api)

Comment: Please [edit] this post rather than link to another account

Answer (score 1):

I've also faced the same problem. The issue is reported but still not fixed: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65793314

Comment: Thanks for your answer.