# Android studio 3.1.3 not show any error when i use deprecated api

Tags: android, android-studio-3.1.3

I use android studio 3.1.3 . When i write deprecated method (for example:

```
  Spanned a= Html.fromHtml("<b>hello</b>");
```

android studio code editor not show any error  or suggestion  and not highlighting deprecated methods like android studio 2.3!!! and when i rebuild(compile) project this give me below error.

> ... \MainActivity.java:
>       uses or overrides a deprecated API.
>       Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details

Please help me.

My build.gradle (Module:app) :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.my.mynewapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    } }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this things..
in app level gradle build change this things..

```
    compileSdkVersion 27   // hear you can define any sdk.
```

and all dependency according to 27 .. remove 28 alpha

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

i tried this code and it working define into onCreate method into activity.

```
        TextView textView=findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Spanned a= Html.fromHtml("<b>hello</b>");
    textView.setText(a);
```

Comment: I change it and rebuild project but problem not solved.

Comment: I added build.gradle to question please see it.

Comment: i update my answer. and also android studio invalided/restart .

Comment: I invalided/restart android studio but unfortunately my editor not show any error or suggestion for deprecated api.

Comment: once try to restart studio.

Comment: because i test and show hello in bold into textview.

Comment: This work fine when i run it on device but still give an warning (... \MainActivity.java:
uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.)